# How to keep UIMenuController Visible on Orientation change in

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I have intialized `UIMenuController` by `sharedMenuController` Method. I have added MenuItems in Menu and display `UIMenuController` on `LongPress` event. Now the issue I am facing is If i change the orientation of iPhone and `UIMenuController` is visible than it goes invisible. Here,  if the Menu is Visible than I want to keep visible on orientation change.

Can anybody suggest me where I can look up for the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's apps seem to re-display the menu at the end of an orientation change (you can see it fade out and back in), so you should probably do the same thing in your app.

The easiest way to do this is probably to override your view controller's `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to set a flag indicating if the menu is visible, and then override `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` to check that flag and display the menu if needed. If you want to do this in a `UIView` subclass instead of a view controller, you may want to observe `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me give it a try.

Comment: I have implemented as you sugggest and thing is working fine. Thanks.